# How to configure pc desktop + mac laptop workstation?

Tags: windows, macos, multiple-monitors, workstation

This is probably simpler than I'm imagining, but I've got a Windows desktop with 2 monitors connected with 2 DVI cables. I've worked with this setup for years.

I want to add a Macbook Pro to the mix, switching computers but maintaining at least one of the secondary monitors while using the laptop, if not both.

What cables, switches, splitters would accomodate this most seamlessly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't so simple.

Here goes...

[Display port to DVI-Link adapter](http://www.startech.com/AV/Displayport-Converters?fam_filter=MDP-to-DVI&gclid=CJ6x76bhhrQCFUlxQgodJ0cAiQ) (single or dual) will drive one monitor. For the other monitor: [USB to DVI](http://eshop.macsales.com/item/NewerTech/VIDU2DVIA/).

And then a [KVM to switch between the two platforms](http://www.neworldit.com/ProductDetails.asp?ProductCode=27380069301&gclid=CMLN6dvghrQCFSmCQgodhiAAjQ).

Good luck! :)

Comment: Ouch. I think I'll forgo the $250 switch and just add the USB to DVI cable (already have the display port to DVI). Thanks.